# Object Model calls may fail from WorkbookOpen event when exiting Protected View

Tags: excel, vba

in my workbook_open event I have some code that promptes the Run-time error 1004(see picture).

[image]

I assume [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/object-model-calls-may-fail-from-workbookopen-event-when-exiting-protected-view-35997715-bc38-5f25-a95c-847fe546a78c) is my problem. But I can't find any good solution, I'm not able to use the code in the link (or get it to work). I have done some research but none of the previous questions include any good answer.

Quick about the problem: when leaving "protected view"(by pressing "enable edit") the workbook_open is triggered, but the file hasn't actually been opened, so the code "worksheets("...") returns null and the error is displayed.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
Global CombinationRange As Range
Global FirstTimeOpen As Range
Global FirstTimeOpenToday As Range
Global BuildNumber As Range

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Call LoadVariables
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "LoginPage" Then
        Else
        ws.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
    
    'Depending on the file was newly created or not, open applicable LoginForm
    If FirstTimeOpen = "No" Then
        Startpage.show
        Else
        Loginform.show
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub LoadVariables()

'General
'======================================================================================================================================================
    Set CombinationRange = Worksheets("Master").Range("GZ8:GZ20") ' Range whereas all correct login are to activate users.
    Set FirstTimeOpen = Worksheets("Basic Data").Range("S4") ' Displays "Yes" or "No" depending on if this is the first time the files is opened
    Set FirstTimeOpenToday = Worksheets("Basic Data").Range("S7") ' Displays "Yes" or "No" depending on if this is the first time the files is opened today.
    Set BuildNumber = Worksheets("Basic Data").Range("N193")
'======================================================================================================================================================

End Sub
```

Note that this workbook will be opened by a lot of different people so changing my settings in the trust center is no solution.

Any ideas how to avoid this error?

Comment: The linked Microsoft site suggests to move the code to the `WorkbookActivate`-event. Have you tried?

Comment: Since Excel open it in 'Protected view' it suspects the file like having a problematic origine... Testing the above suggestion, my work, but it should be good to also skip the 'Protected view` itself. Did you test adding its path to the Trusted Locations folder? I saw your final note, but if it works, I remember that I've done a piece of code to automatically add a specific file path to this Trusted Locations folder. I did it for CorelDRAW, but it should work even better in Excel. I mean, this piece of code should check if the workbook path is added in that folder and if not, add it.

Comment: Maybe, in `Workbook_Activate` event...

Comment: @FunThomas  Yes I tried that, but I don't fully understand the code, and nothing happened when I put the code in a "class module".

Comment: @FaneDuru, that sound intereseting. Logically it seems like that shouldn't work but i'm ready to give it a try. I havn't tested adding it as a trusted location, but when opening the file normally (without protecting view) the code does exactly what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @FaneDuru Do you have any hints on how I would go about adding a trusted location with code?

Comment: I have, I told you in my previous comment. But you did not really ask my question... When asking "Did you test adding its path to the Trusted Locations folder?", I wonted to know if after adding it in those Trusted Locations, it opens normally, without any Protected View. It can open in 'Protected view' because of other reasons and I do not want to spend time to search for the code in discussion, or recreate it, if it will not solve your problem. I found a piece of code on the internet and I adapted to do what I needed. Writing a marker in Registry and checking it at the next run.

Comment: And, it is easy to manually add the folder and test how it opens...

Comment: @FaneDuru ok, after some thinking I'm not sure this is such a good idea. Some users will open this file directly from an email, and making that a "trusted location" is not something I should do. I'd prefer a solution that doesn't include removing the "protected view". Thank you anyway!

Comment: @FunThomas, Do you have any idea what I could be doing wrong when trying to implement the code? I've basically just pasted the code from the link to a class module. I've written (msgbox "1") in the subs to try debugging it, but it appears that none of the subs is running when I start the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: this is not an answer. simply a get around I used.

Due to this problem I had to find another way to run my code when starting the file. I solved this by writing code that would run when saving the file instead, meaning I don't have the problem of "protecting view". I'm "forcing" the file to go into a "log out" mode whereas all sheets have been hidden and protected (all column are also hidden) with the exception of the "loginpage". And when you are opening the file, you are prompted to click a buttion which will then run the code that I was trying to have in "workbook_open".

It solved my problem, but not the problem above. As my solution was to simply skip the "workbook_open" event.

Note: This also solved another problem of me, when the file was opened "protecting view", some sheet were still visible, which would have been hidden by my code that was going to be run at "workbook_open".

Code I used:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Call LoadVariables

    
    LoadingForm.show (vbModeless)
    LoadingForm.Caption = "Logging out"
    LoadingForm.Repaint
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Call UnProtectSheet("Basic Data")
    FirstTimeOpenToday = "No"
    
    Call ActivateUser("LoginUser")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    LoadingForm.Caption = "Changing User"
    LoadingForm.hide
    
End Sub


Sub Login()

    Call LoadVariables
    
    'Resetting so that the file knows that this is the first time opening the file today
    Call UnProtectSheet("Basic Data")
    FirstTimeOpenToday = "No"
    
    'Depending on the file was newly created or not, open applicable LoginForm
    If FirstTimeOpen = "No" Then
        Startpage.show
        Else
        Loginform.show
    End If
End Sub
```